Get search results product collection
I am creating an search results dropdown for the site header. I have created several dataproviders that search for a keyword for different entities/content.
When I include a products dataprovider to search for products, it is extremely slow returning results. The product catalog has 20000 products.
I am using the class:
Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Search\Collection

With the code below:
        $collection = $this->productCollection;
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['entity_id', 'name', 'description', 'price']);
        $collection->addSearchFilter($query);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
        $collection->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());

The actual search results page loads quite fast, and so am I using the best approach to get a product search collection? Is there a better, quicker way?
On my local site version, the results are returned very quickly. On a remote staging site the results are extremely slow to load. The server has plenty of memory and has been optimised for performance.


Limit the collection size for dropdown
$collection->setPageSize(5);  // Only get what you need for the dropdown

Add caching layer

Optimize the selected attributes

Add proper indexes


... list continues.
